# Inflating RelativeLayout within another RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to contain the layout model for a custom list view in a single custom list view layout.xml file and inflate that using an custom adaptor class using kotlin.

The data seems to come through fine and the row formatting is accurate with the exception of the header being repeated for each row.  I'm guessing I could just move the header out of the list view layout.xml file but I'd prefer to keep that self contained so it could be re-used.

This is the layout file in question:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- Header aligned to top -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/estimated_ftp_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/colorHeader"
    android:gravity="start" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:text="@string/estimated_ftp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Content below header -->

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:layout_below="@id/estimated_ftp_header"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dip"
    android:id="@+id/estimated_ftp_row">

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/ftp_type"
        android:id="@+id/ftp_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/centerPoint"
        android:gravity = "center|end|end"
        android:src="@drawable/glyphicons_13_heart"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/centerPoint"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ftp_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/centerPoint"
        android:gravity = "center|start|start"
        android:text="141 bpm"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I believe the solution would be to figure out how to select the estimated_ftp_row id and inflate it instead of the the whole estimated_fto.xml file.

Here is the code in the adapter that selects the layout before inflating within the getView method:

```
val inflater = activity?.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.estimated_ftp, null)
viewHolder = ViewHolder(view)
view?.tag = viewHolder
```

How would I change the inflater.inflate to inflate something within R.layout.estimated_ftp?

FWIW, the activity's XML layout has a ListView control in the location used for this as a placeholder.  It doesn't reference the custom layout file.  That connection is done via the adapter class noted above.  Not sure that's a problem or not so I wanted to mention it...

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

mike

Solution Update:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m had the guidance I needed.  I was able to separate the row format from the header format XML layouts.  The Adapter was unchanged and the Activity has new code to add the header if content is found for the list in question.

```
val headerView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.estimated_ftp_head, null)
estimated_ftp_list.addHeaderView(headerView)
```

Comment: You can't inflate just part of a layout. When you inflate one, it's the whole thing. You need to have two separate layouts; one for the header, and one for the items. `ListView` supports headers separately from items, so you can just add that header `View` once, instead of trying to somehow remove it from every item but the first. Also, I'm not sure exactly what you mean by re-use, but if you need those layouts combined as one in some other part of your app, you can always inflate one into the other, at that point.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I'll edit the post now with your solution.

Comment: Please post the solution as answer, this way people know that the issue is solved. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m had the guidance I needed. I was able to separate the row format from the header format XML layouts. The Adapter was unchanged and the Activity has new code to add the header if content is found for the list in question.

```
val headerView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.estimated_ftp_head, null)
estimated_ftp_list.addHeaderView(headerView)
```